# linearlayout not matching parent width android

Tags: android

Just a disclaimer on my part before I start relaying my question. This is my first time posting in hopes of finding a probable solution online and I'd done prior searches on the internet but failed to find the solution to my problem.

[image]

The issue I encountered was, while trying to match the width of L2 with its parent, L4, L2 gets the width correctly but there are some paddings at all four of its sides which I can't seem to get rid off. I'd checked my layout files and activities class, and I'm sure that I'm not making any changes to the layout programmatically. My layout files are as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/segment_agenda"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStartTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"         
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Start Time Here"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:src="@drawable/information" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEndTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"        
        android:text="End Time Here"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="@drawable/tabbarunselectedipad"

    >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Title Here"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="SubTitle Here"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_info"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem solved, It was padding from another drawable resource that was being set programmatically as the background of my Linear Layout L4. Thanks people and sorry to trouble you guys for my carelessness, will be more careful and check through my codes thoroughly before posting for help in the future.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What exactly layout you want and what you are getting ? Where are you getting space ? In L1 ?

Comment: Sorry guys, it was carelessness on my part. I traced everything backwards and found out that the L4 background was set programmatically instead of within the layout file.

Comment: And i found out that the drawable resource I used had specified paddings within it, everything is fine now, thanks people. Is there anyway I can close this thread?

Comment: Yes you can close your question by selecting close on option below your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please You Should Remove android:weightSum="1" of all places in Your layout and try..It should be work....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/segment_agenda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStartTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Text 1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtEndTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Text 2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="#37c100" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Title Here"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="SubTitle Here"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_width="14dp"
                android:layout_height="14dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout_width="0dp" in every LinearLayout which have layout_weight param

Comment: The weights are for the setting the heights of both L1 and L2 so if i attempt to set a layout_width="0dp" in them, i'll get "Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for 
 layout_height" and I can't even run the project.

Comment: Your L1 and L2 weight sums = 1.1